# React throws Invalid hook call error, why is that?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Contact = () => {
 const [data] = useState({
    fullname: '',
    //More data here
 });
 const formSubmit = () => {
    // Some more Code
 };
 return (
    <>
     <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">
                  Full Name
            </label>
            <input
               type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="exampleFormControlInput1"
               name="fullname"
               value={data.fullname}     
               //onChange={InputEvent}
               placeholder=" Your name"
               required
            />
        </div>
     </form>
    </>
 );
}
```

I want to useState full name in the value and I did `data.fullname` what's wrong with this and why am I getting **Invalid Hook call** error.

*Note:- I already commented Onchange this thing is nothing to do with hooks and also OnSubmit has more code.*

Comment: its working good. https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-lewin-u216i ..

Comment: @prasanth In VScode It's not working, do you have any idea what is wrong with my VS code editor or anything else

Comment: your return statement has opening `(` but no closing `)`

Comment: @theTradeCoder  update:- return closing tag added 
it's there in the code but I forgot to add in here.

Comment: Your code is running well - problem is coming from somewhere else...

Comment: @AkshayJain show your package.json react version

Comment: @prasanth `{
  "name": "demowebsite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

I used `react@v17.0.1` and `react-dom@v17.0.1`, like the error says `You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)` so update both your `react` and `react-dom` to latest and you're all good

Comment: My `react@v17.0.1` and `react-dom@v17.0.1` and also `react-router-dom@v5.2.0` as you mentioned both react and react-dom versions are the same. what should I do now?

Comment: what?hahaha, then something else is happening, can you try deleting `node_modules/` and `npm install` again, just to see if something messed up in node_modules dir, and can you paste your package.json content?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, reinstall/update the node modules

Comment: @NikkoKhresna I created a new project and copy my code files in there still I am getting the same error. what should I do?

Comment: try `echo $NODE_PATH` in terminal, what does it give you?

Comment: @NikkoKhresna nothing, It gave me nothing, can you tell me how it works. I haven't heard or use it.